# If "The Blue Shadow Virus" was eradicated, does the technology exist to eradicate all diseases?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In Season 1 Episode 17 of The Clone Wars (*Blue Shadow Virus*) they are trying to prevent a strain of a previously-extinct plague from being recreated.

In the episode, we learn that the virus was entirely eradicated:

> Padmé: "But the Blue Shadow Virus is deadly to most lifeforms... That's why it was wiped out."

Obviously, the latter part of this makes one wonder about the power and effectiveness of star wars technology: if they can "wipe out" one virus on the grounds of it being 'too destructive', does the technology exist to eradicate all diseases?

Comment: Knowing how to eradicate one virus doesn't mean you can eradicate another. We pretty much eradicated polio but influenza...that's still around.

Comment: What @Pauli_D said... us plain ol' humans have eradicated Smallpox. So we can eradicate **some** viruses, namely those susceptible to the technology of vaccines and where both global and local politics have made it possible (Polio still exists in the wild because of the latter). Other viruses are not so easy, like HIV and the 200 different virus strains that cause the common cold.

Comment: The worst question I encountered in a while.. Which kind of logic is that? Did you think about flying nanobots shooting viruses with lasers?

Comment: @Bat No? There hasn't been any indication that nanobots exist in the Star Wars universe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, this is what is known as a [Hasty Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization). Not all diseases are created equal or require the same information, resources, or tech to defeat. It's like asking, "Since we have a vaccine for the flu, are we capable of making vaccine for anything?"

Though much more prevalent in Legends, there are many examples of diseases still being around. No less than seven mentioned in the question you linked.

And then you have the Blue Shadow itself, proving that even if they have the tech to eradicate it, they also have the tech to bring it back.

Finally, if you mean to ask "Do they have the technology to eradicate a disease if they *wanted* to?" I'd say the answer is no. If they did, then they would have done so already. Look at our world, even amidst the war and turmoil here, we still have people working to eradicate viruses. In a galaxy as technologically capable as Star Wars, they would have had the people to work on it. And since they have the people, and they still have the diseases, we can make an educated guess that they don't have the technology yet.

Comment: "If they did [have the ability to eradicate a disease], then they would have done so already". I disagree because this is certainly not true in the real world. [Polio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poliomyelitis_eradication) was something people thought would be eliminated by 2000, yet here we are still seeing cases in third world countries, due to a lack of health infrastructure and too many civil wars.

Comment: Thereby showing we are incapable of eradicating it yet. I realize we are technically able, but I'm trying to avoid adding qualifiers here. *If* third-world countries would get better health infrastructure, *then* we could eradicate polio. But there is also conceivably some tech that would allow us to cure and eradicate without needing this prerequisite or some breakthrough that will allow us to fulfill that prerequisite and overcome whatever is preventing us doing so now.

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples in the answers of [the question you linked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168337/46383) of diseases that are both serious and currently incurable.
Examples include the [Borotavi Syndrome](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Borotavi_syndrome) which the Jedi Council itself, during the Clone Wars, was unable to cure within a single individual.